# react-starter-kit: How can I export graphql schema for Relay Modern?

Tags: schema, graphql, relay, react-starter-kit

I would like to add Relay Modern to my app started from **react-starter-kit**. `relay-compiler` needs a schema definition file (`schema.graphql`), how can I generate it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [get-graphql-schema](https://github.com/graphcool/get-graphql-schema) for that:

```
npm install -g get-graphql-schema
get-graphql-schema ENDPOINT_URL > schema.graphql
```

This is based on a GraphQL introspection query, [here's more information](https://www.graph.cool/docs/faq/graphql-how-to-download-graphql-idl-schema-maiv5eekan/).

Comment: Probably a strongly react-starter-kit related question, but as I see, I need a running server to export the schema this way. Is there any possibility to generate statically somehow? (... to build the whole isomorphic app in one step)

Comment: Could you try looking into https://github.com/graphcool/babel-plugin-react-relay maybe? It's been written for Relay Classic so you might need to adjust it.